# Geocoder Gem Ruby

Tags: ruby, google-maps, reverse-geocoding, rails-geocoder

If I plug in a coords into Geocoder, for example Lat:88, Lng:88 the response will be nil. This is correct

```
2.2.3 :001 > Geocoder.address([88, 88])
Geocoder: HTTP request being made for https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=&language=en&latlng=88%2C88&sensor=false
 => nil
```

But if I'm over my Daily or Request Per Second Query Limit or there is no internet connection the response will also be nil, ...lets say for a real coords like NYC ( lat:40.7127, lng:-74.0059)

```
2.2.3 :002 > Geocoder.address([40.7127, -74])
Geocoder: HTTP request being made for https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=&language=en&latlng=40.7127%2C-74&sensor=false
Geocoding API connection cannot be established.
 => nil
```

Is there a way to determine if it's a real coords with a nil address or a API/Internet issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in the **Error Handling** section of [Geocoder's github readme](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#error-handling)

```
Geocoder.configure(:always_raise => :all)
```

is what you're looking for.